# How To Display WebSocket Data into Browser PHP

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

Here is my Question:
i just created simple websocket using php language, everything is working fine and successfully receiving message from client in CMD.

i want to show client response into browser instead of CMD.

Here is my code Please let me know how its possible.
i also attached CMD response image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvfJs.png)

First File Code (server.php)

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "80446";
set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Socket Create Not Working');

$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die ('Socket Bind Not Working in Result');

$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die('Socket Listen Not Working');
// echo "Listening for connections";

do{
$accept = socket_accept($socket) or die('Accept Not Working');
$message = socket_read($accept, 1024);
$message = trim($message);
echo $message . "\n";
}while(true);

socket_close($accept);
socket_close($socket);

?>
```

2nd File Code (client.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['message']!='') {

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "80446";
set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Socket Create Not Working');

socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die('Socket Connect Not Working');

$message = $_POST['message'];
// $message = "hello socket";

socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message));

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Client Side WebSocket</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI this is not technically a websocket - that's a specific protocol which sits on top of raw sockets and HTTP. If you want the data to appear in the browser then the _browser_ (using Javascript) should connect to the websocket server and listen for messages. You didn't say precisely what is going wrong here, but I can probably guess - if you write the PHP code as you have done here, you'll have an infinite loop where the PHP script never ends, and thus never returns a response to the browser...a HTTP response comes all at once when the script ends (unless you use output buffering)

Comment: There is an existing PHP websocket server implementation done by [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) which will probably be a lot simpler to work with than trying to re-invent the wheel again with your own solution. But PHP is [not ideally suited as a websocket server](https://itnext.io/the-reality-of-php-websockets-4c680bc2bc60) due to its minimal support for async and multithreading. Maybe look into using something like nodeJS or ASP.NET with SignalR, they make a much better job of it on the whole.

Comment: @ADyson Thank You so much For Your Response, Please let me know How its work any example of this line in Your comment ( If you want the data to appear in the browser then the browser (using Javascript) should connect to the websocket server and listen for messages.) ?

Comment: There are a billion and one examples out there, look at any websocket tutorial showing the client-side connection method, it's very standard (no matter how the backend is implemented). BUT...it won't connect to the PHP code you've written here because as I mentioned above your PHP code does not implement the websocket protocol. Firstly start by using a proper websocket server instead of trying to write your own.

Comment: You can try to see as idea to https://github.com/walkor/Workerman